# What argument should I throw when a function that should only be called once is called again?

Tags: java

A little more context: I have a listener class that listens on network connections. Its `listen` method should not be called on it twice. What should I throw when it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a predefined exception, you might throw `IllegalStateException`, since the object is already in the `listening` state.

If you do this, though, there should be a way for the client to find out if `listen` has already been called. E.g. an `isListening()` method.

You might also create your own exception, possibly extended from IOException, since this is an IO Problem. Presumably, attempting to listen more than once fails since the network resource has already been used on the first listen. (Similar to sockets binding.)

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a logical error that can only occur when the client of your library is using it incorrectly, the exception you throw should be an unchecked exception (e.g. `java.lang.RuntimeException` or a derivative thereof) as opposed to a checked exception.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException` is intended for that purpose:

> "Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time"

But it could also be an exception in your own custom made exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would throw a `IllegalStateException`. It is normally used to indicate that the user tried to make something which is not legal in the current state of the object.